# converting multilines user input into single line

Tags: python, multiline

I just started programming and created my first code which is a word counter.
When I tested my code, it works on interactive window but not on the terminal because the terminal cannot accept multi-line input e.g. paragraphs. So, when I compile my code into exe, it cannot work unless I somehow convert the entire paragraph into a single line. Does anyone know any workaround to this problem? Thank you.

Hello, an edit here since I saw someone asked for the code for better help (p.s: the code worked perfectly though, it just can't accept a whole paragraph as input because there are 'enter' in paragraph, which counted as user enter and in turns, running the next code, and breaking them.):

```
#"full filter" show original word lenght, filter lenght, and filtered word lenght.
print('James first coding, Words Counter .2x')
sentence = str(input("""give me the word that you want to analyse: """)).replace(",","").replace('"',"").replace(".",'').replace("!",'').replace("?",'').replace(":",'').replace(";",'').replace("$",'')
words = sentence.split()
word_lim = int(input("minimum world lenght: "))
result = []

for word in words:
    if len(word) > word_lim:
        result.append(word)


print("original word lenght: ",len(words))
print("filter lenght: ",word_lim)
print("Result:  ")
print("Total words: ", len(result))
print("total alphabets:",sum([len(x) for x in result]))
input('Press ENTER to exit')
```

Comment: You can use input in a loop while the user didn't sent the EOF signal and then concatenate all the results into one single string.

Comment: Can you perhaps share your code so that someone might be able to help you? Also some debugging details would be helpful

Comment: Question needs some code:
Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
print("Enter your content, Ctrl-D and Enter to save it.") 
contents = [] 
while True: 
    try: 
        line = input() 
    except EOFError: 
        break 
    contents.append(line)
print(*contents, sep = " ")
```

Enter your string in multiple lines. Once you complete giving the user input in multiple lines, press `ctrl+d`. It sends a `signalEOF` to your system.

If you are a windows user, use `ctrl+z` instead of `ctrl+d`. And `enter`.